# A good way to maintain a resume on Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a way to maintain my personal resume on Wordpress.  In the past, I've used an old OpenOffice template, but it doesn't work that well anymore and doesn't support hResume.

I've been looking around and none of the Resume plugins work that well.

In fact, the best Resume editor I've seen is on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/.  But I don't want my resume on someone else's site. I want it on my site.

Ideally, it would have nice markup, with hResume microformatting.  Maybe ODF and PDF versions automatically generated.

Actually, there is no reason for the editor and the display portion to be part of the same tool.

I'm hoping there is one out there already so I don't have to write it myself or just hand code it.

Comment: Are you wanting to allow others to post resumes or are you just looking for a way to post your own resume? If the latter, why do you need a plugin? Just put it in a WordPress page. 

If you need help with the markup, put your resume on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ and use View Source to see what markup they use.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that I want a personal resume.  You should put that as an answer, it's not bad...more work than I want, but not bad.

Comment: It seems to me that unless you are maintaining your resume **very** frequently, you will spend way more time finding, installing and configuring a plugin than you will save in manually adjusting the resume in a standard WP page.

Comment: Sure, but if I have the need for it, so will other people.  I try to update my resume about once every 6 months or as needed.

I keep needing to switch tools for updating my resume because I've been doing it for so many years. I don't even recall all the editors I've had to use.

hResume looks like something that begins to do something forward compatible.  Leaving off the editor part would be fine -- I can write HTML well enough.  But I still want PDF, ODF, etc. output for employers that demand it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly/fully, but I remember that the XSLT plugin was used for something like to display / render a resume / cv online:

- [Xslt Processor (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xslprocessor/)

Comment: I just whipped up a simple xslt processor that uses the Careers site's hResume to build a simple page using xsltproc.  Not bad, so this might be a good way to go. It needs a nice stylesheet and a way to get PDF and ODF out of it, though.

Comment: That's nice feedback. PIWI ships with stuff to render out PDF and DOC (maybe so ODT?), it's a bit more complicated than wordpress but still compact: http://www.piwiframework.de/ - This might bear more impressions for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for something like WP Resume:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-resume/
- http://ben.balter.com/2010/09/12/wordpress-resume-plugin/